# Show data difference in columns of two tables in same database

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and doing data analysis by using different queries. In my database I have 70 columns each in two different tables in same schema. The data in those tables were entered twice. Now I am comparing data of each column and showing records which have differences. Below is my query.

```
SELECT 
    [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF].Student_Class4_15,
    [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF_old].Student_Class4_15
FROM
    [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF]
INNER JOIN
    [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF_old] ON [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF].FormID = [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF_old].FormID
WHERE
    [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF].Student_Class4_15 <> [NEEF_Entry].[dbo].[tbl_TOF_old].Student_Class4_15
```

The join is based in the form ID which is same in both the tables. Now the column here is `Student_Class4_15` in table `tbl_TOF` and in table `tbl_TOF_old` which is being compared here and [the output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4kq.jpg)

It shows what is the difference when data was entered before and after. Now the problem with this is that I have to manually replace column names of 70 columns each time which is time consuming.

What I want is that SQL query should pick all columns and compare them and return results.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL doesn't do that.  But you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to generate the queries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use except to compare two tables, If the query returns no rows then the data is the same.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
EXCEPT  
SELECT *
FROM table2;
```

In case table2 has an extra rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
EXCEPT  
SELECT *
FROM table1;
```

Comment: it gives this error All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: you need to select the columns that you need to compare,

Comment: I want to compare every column and there are 70 columns

Comment: are you sure both two tables have 70 columns? Column counts need to be the same.